How to add another autofilter to my textbox in excel
I have a DB on excel with a table autofilter using a textbox, i'm trying to add another filter to the same textbox but duplicating the range and field doesn't work, i'm not an expert in VBA so i need some help to figure out.
nombre = "*" & Sheets("DATOS").TextBox1.Text & "*"
Range("B5").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=nombre
Range("C3").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=estado

Thanks!

Could you explain why there are different rows in Range? Additionally, doesn't work is not very descriptive. Could you provide more details? [ask]
